# Blazor rendering optimalisation for data driven components

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm stuck as how to optimize rendering of a typical data-driven Blazor component. Consider the following simplified component (partial):

```
public partial class FooComponent: ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected IBarService BarService { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string OptionalParameter1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter] 
    public string OptionalParameter2 { get; set; };

    protected IEnumerable<BarItem> Items { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        this.Items = await this.BarService.GetItemsAsync(this.OptionalParameter1, this.OptionalParameter2);
    }
}
```

The component has two optional parameters. They could typically be some filtering values for the service call. The component has no way of knowing whether any of these parameters will be set by the parent component (since they are optional). Whenever a parameter is set, the component retrieves a list of `BarItem` items via an (expensive) async service call. The component markup then renders the `Items` list in some way.

The problem is that `OnParametersSetAsync` is called everytime a parameter is set, causing the component to re-render and do another service call. I can partially optimize this by checking if the parameter values have changed, but there will still be multiple service calls.

- If both parameters are never set, the service call happens once (good).
- If one parameter is set, the service call happens twice (first time with wrong parameter values).
- If both parameters are set, the service call happens 3 times (first 2 times with wrong parameter values).

In a real-world component with more properties this can quickly result in many unwanted service calls. If `OnParametersSetAsync` would be called once for all parameters, this would not be a problem (I understand that Blazor does not work this way).

Is there something I can do to make sure service calls only happen once with the correct parameter values? This seems to me like a very common scenario in data-driven components, and it would be a real shortcoming for Blazor if this is not possible to implement (efficiently).

Comment: Use OnInitializedAsync instead

Comment: @aguafrommars parameters have not yet been set at OnInitializedAsync and is called only once

Comment: Sorry `OnAfterRenderAsync`

Comment: OnAfterRender wouldn’t work either because the component is already rendered so it’s too late for data retrieval

Comment: First of all, do you actually have a problem with render speed?  The amount of time taken to rerender a component (it's literally just outputting HTML right?) might be trivial.  Don't spend time fixing it unless you can see it's actually broken.  Second,  you can use conditional logic to render nothing on your first pass.  Put this at the top of your markup: `@if (!MyStuffIsAllLoaded) { returrn;}`  Then in `OnParametersSetAsync` you can check if you have all the data you need to proceed with rendering, and set `MyStuffIsAllLoaded = true;`  But I've never had to do this kind of "optimization."

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday in dotnet Conf Focus Blazor, Daniel Roth showcased something similar. 
To solve the issue you can use a timer that starts each time one of the parameters are set. And if the timer hits the time limit you invoke the search request.
This is called debounce.

[Youtube link to the part](https://youtu.be/fgneZz-4Foc?t=1406)

I will try to dig out the github repo for the demo if I can.

Answer (score 0):

As I faced this issue as well, I can also agree it is quite tedious. Here, I have some feedback in the form of a list, based on my painful experience. I hope you find this useful; if not, simply ignore it.

1. Avoid reference types in parameters. If I remember correctly (hopefully), reference types always trigger OnParametersSet, whereas value types do so only if there was a change.
2. Use nullable types like string?, bool?, int? so you can check if a parameter was set.
3. When checking if parameters have changed, I always declare [Parameter] with the prefix 'Param' and a property which I actually use in the component beneath it, so I never get bamboozled. Example bellow:

   ```
    @code {

    [Parameter] public string? PARAMOptionalParameter1 { get; set; }
    private string? OptionalParameter1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string? PARAMOptionalParameter2 { get; set; }
    private string? OptionalParameter2 { get; set; }

    private bool _shouldRender;
    private bool _shouldDownloadData;

    private void FunctionToCheckForParamtersChange()
    {
        _shouldRender = false;
        _shouldDownloadData = false;

        if (PARAMOptionalParameter1 == OptionalParameter1)
        {
            // Do nothing or whatever you like
        }
        else
        {
            OptionalParameter1 = PARAMOptionalParameter1; 
            _shouldRender = true;
            _shouldDownloadData = true;
        }
        //Other stuff and parameters, you get the idea
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        return _shouldRender;
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        FunctionToCheckForParamtersChange();
        if (_shouldDownloadData)
        {
            // DATA download
        }
    }
   }
   ```
4. The cleanest way is to group all your parameters into a class/struct named YourComponentConfig. Implement a custom comparer for this class or struct, and include a boolean flag to indicate whether all parameters are set. As a result, you can simplify the FunctionToCheckForParametersChange method to a single line: if (ParamConfig == Config).
5. Alternatively, you can use a less conventional approach by creating a reference to the component and modifying its parameters directly from the parent controller (although option 5 is preferable). For example:

   <Component @ref ="ComponentRef" />

   @code
   {
   Component? ComponentRef{get;set;}

   void SetData(){
   ComponentRef?.SetMyData("Data1","Data2"); // Remember that our custom SetMyData method is out of render circle, so you should put in SetMyData InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) for render to happen.
   }
   }